# Making POST request to rest api and then making GET request to get additional data for the resource being added

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to think of a best way to architect my back-end rest api. I have the following requirement:

1. Client makes a post request with to add a resource that contains an ID and meta information
2. Before I add this resource to the database I need to make a GET request to a third party API with the ID provided to fetch related data.
3. Then save the original resource and its related data to the database

Currently in the `Repository` inside the `AddAsync` method, before I persist the resource to the database, I make a call to the third party API to GET detail information about the resource based on the ID and THEN perform `SaveChangesAsync` on the model which has the rest of its properties populated by the GET request.

This however feels wrong since I am making a `POST` request from my client and then a `GET` request on the backend server. Is there a better way of solving this?

```
IAccountRepository:

public async Task<SupervisorResult> AddAsync(Account newAccount, CancellationToken ct = default)
        {        
            // GetAccountDataAsync fetches order data that I need to save whenever new Account is added    
            SupervisorResult result = await GetAccountDataAsync(newAccount, ct);
                    

            if(result.Succeeded == false)
            {
                _logger.Here().Debug("Failed to get new account data.");
                return result;
            }

            Account freshAccount = (Account)result.Value;

            _dbContext.Accounts.Add(freshAccount);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(ct);

            result.Succeeded = true;
            result.Value = freshAccount;

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: make the GET request first from the client and build the complete object then make the POST request to the server ?

Comment: It entirely depends on the nature of the GET request and how you want to handle orchestration.  If the GET contains sensitive data that should not be exposed to the clients, or contains sensitive credentials, it must be done serverside.  That said, I would never recommend doing this check at the persistence layer. Typically this should be raised up one layer to a logical layer before you've potentially constructed contexts.  That said, overall, there is nothing inherently wrong with this approach.

Comment: The GET request may contain sensitive information. It is also a large payload, so its best to handle it server side. I can raise this up to my logical layer without any issues. I was considering exploring the CQRS pattern for this but I am not sure if the complexity of CQRS outweighs the benefit. Basically add the initial resource in the db post to queue to fetch the rest of the data, then update the db once we fetched the data. But ok, if there isn't anything wrong with POST > GET > save approach then I might just keep moving forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view I don't think it's a problem to do a GET call in that situation.
Probably the best approach should be to manage possible exception from the `GetAccountDataAsync`.

In case a user send all the correct data, but your external system has some problem to create the account, is not responsibility of your user to "retry" the process.
This improvement could be costly, but should be better in the user experience.

I think the approach described from David (raise up one layer) is correct, so do I prefer to segregate the responsibility of the communication with external system to the application/logical layer.

In case of a *partial* completion of the saving process the user (Account) should be in a sort of *waiting state*.

Comment: ok that is good to know. I will move ahead and just move that logic to the application core/logical layer and keep moving forward.